# \mathbb{Z} is not working properly for \not?

Tags: breqn, mathbb

I am using pdflatex on Ubuntu 20.04.2. I wrote the following latex code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,breqn}
\newcommand{\bZ}{{\mathbb Z}}
\newcommand{\lhdZl}{\lhd_{\bZ^{l}}}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{align}
   a &\not\lhdZl b\\
   a &\not\lhd_{\bZ^{l}} b
 \end{align}
\end{document}
```

It seems to me that two lines in the align environment are supposed to give the same expressions, because the first one uses `\lhdZl`, which is defined as `\lhd_{\bZ^{l}}`, and the second one just uses `\lhd_{\bZ^{l}}`. However, the resulting pdf below puts the first one not with the `\mathbb Z` and the second one with the `\mathbb Z`.

[image: mathbbZ with not]

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The obvious problem is `breqn`.

A couple of fixes at the beginning:

1. the correct syntax is `\mathbb{Z}`, not `{\mathbb Z}`;
2. `\lhd` is *not* defined as a binary relation symbol.

Fix without `breqn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\bZ}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\nsg}{\mathrel{\lhd}} % normal subgroup
\newcommand{\nsgZl}{\nsg_{\bZ^{l}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
   a &\not\nsgZl b\\
   a &\not\nsg_{\bZ^{l}} b
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now let's try with `breqn`. No, it doesn't work. Sorry. What can you do? Don't use `breqn`.

Apparently, `breqn` (or, rather, `flexisym`) wants to see an explicit `_` after the negated symbol and hiding it in a macro will ruin everything. And, for strange reasons, making `\lhd` into a binary relation symbol will make `\not` unable to recognize it as such. Which is a bug in `breqn`: for instance, also `\not\sqsubset` produces a correct result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's very clear. I hope the bug gets fixed, because sometimes I use breqn for the dmath environment.